# XLPagerTabStrip select what view controller will be shown first

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

I'm using [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) to switch among a collection of view controllers. I have three view controllers and I would like that middle view controller is shown by default as first.

I could use

```
let parentViewController = self.parent! as! ParentViewController
parentViewController.moveToViewControllerAtIndex(1)
```

inside my first view controller, but that first view controller loads some data from the server and if I switch to another view controller while it is loading data, that first view controller will freeze and it won't load data.

Is there a way to show middle view controller as first by default?

Comment: this is issue in  XLPagerTabStrip 
you can using `pod 'XLPagerTabStrip' , :git => 'https://github.com/Dagogatc/XLPagerTabStrip.git', :branch => 'moveToViewController-issue'`

Answer (score 3):

jump to the defenition of 'currentIndex' and change it to public from private. then you can select your current controller by this code:

```
currentIndex = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

In function:

```
 override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: 
      PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
            // This line will help you achieve the requirement
            pagerTabStripController.currentIndex = /* required index */


   }
```

It will work smoothly after you make currentIndex in PagerTabStripViewController as public.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent loading the first tab, `moveToViewControllerAtIndex()` must be called before `viewDidLoad()` is called in your `PagerTabStripViewController` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
pagerTabStripController.moveToViewController(at: 0) // required index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Move Specific Tab XLPagerTabStrip in swift 5

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if nowFrom == "sendvc"
    {
        self.moveToViewController(at: 3,animated: false)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following lines:

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.moveToViewController(at: 2)
        reloadPagerTabStripView()
        
    }
```